# Postgres - Is there a way to change data type for some columns permanently only in output (output of SELECT and RETURNING of UPDATE and INSERT)?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I have few tables with some columns have to be decimal. They save data about currency. However, they cannot be translated to float automatically in JavaScript. Postgres suggest saving currency data in decimal or numeric because of they are more accurate. Is there a way to translate them into real or double precision automatically and permanently only in output? Can I add some constraint to achieve my goal?

Because of I have many queries in my JS code, I hope to find out a way to implement it in Postgres. Otherwise, I have to make a lot of changes in my JS code.

Comment: If you using any ORM, the right place would be to do this in the `model` of the table that you want to use.

Comment: @AbhinavD I am using `knex.js` which is just a query builder. I don't think it has `model`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view on top of your table and do conversion there and use view for querying in JS code instead of table. Example of view creation

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT cast(column as integer) as column
FROM table;
```

Comment: I not familiar with the `view`. Is the `view` can work with UPDATE and INSERT? Because of I want the output of RETURNING statement also been translated too.

Comment: @qwang:- Databases do support update and insert via views. Check postgre sql DB documentation to find out details.

Comment: I tried to insert via the view. However, in the view, I tried to convert the column `price` into double precision through `price::double precision` which is the type I wanted. It will return an error `error: cannot insert into column "price" of view "products_view"`, because of the view columns that are not columns of their base relation are not updatable. If I do not use the type translate, then what I asking for is still not been solved.

Comment: @qwang:- Go through your question once. There you have mentioned "only output", Insert and updates are no where mentioned. Better you update your question so that other people can understand it better and answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I was thought that the `RETURNING` statement of `UPDATE` and `INSERT` are included in the 'output'